# unable to Install Perl module LWP::Protocol::https

Tags: perl

i am trying to install perl package LWP::UserAgent using command "sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell; but it gives following error

```
Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp4331'. Giving up on it. at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Index.pm line 225
Fetching with LWP:
  http://www.perl.org/CPAN/autho`rs/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to www.perl.org:80 (connect: No route to host)]

Trying with "/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional" to get
    "http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host


Resolving ftp.perl.org... 204.157.3.70, 209.221.142.115
Connecting to ftp.perl.org|204.157.3.70|:21... failed: No route to host.
Connecting to ftp.perl.org|209.221.142.115|:21... failed: No route to host.


    Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp4331'. Giving up on it. at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Index.pm line 225
No external ftp command available

Your urllist is empty! The urllist can be edited. E.g. with 'o conf urllist
push ftp://myurl/'

Your urllist is empty! The urllist can be edited. E.g. with 'o conf urllist
push ftp://myurl/'

Could not fetch authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Terminal does not support GetHistory.
Lockfile removed.
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can't connect to www.perl.org:80

Looks like your system can not get a connection to the servers providing the software. Either you are offline, blocked by a firewall or you need to configure a proxy to reach the internet. This should affect any tools on the system, not just cpan. Note that any proxy settings you might have in your shell already do not get propagated to perl/cpan when you use sudo.